# What should i do with my parakeet is still on her eggs after 30 days and what happen to her?

Tags: breeding

My parakeet is still in the nesting box with 7 eggs and it been almost 30 days and she is still on them ? What should I do ?? Will she have more eggs soon or do I remove everything? I have 3 females and 2 male in the cage? Should I leave the box in the cage?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want her to lay remove the nesting box, at the 30 day mark you should remove them. It takes about 18-23 days for eggs to hatch, typically the hen will know when it's time to get rid of them.

Normally if you remove their eggs too soon they will lay more however removing the nest box (and anything else that resembles or could be used as a nest) and reduce daylight hours will decrease the need for them to lay eggs.

Another option is to purchase fake egg to replace the real ones so if she wants to sit on them longer you wont have to worry about them rotting.